# ArgumentCaptor for generic method in Mockito

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I have an object that I've mocked. This object has the following method:

```
<R, M extends SomeAbstractClass<R>> List<R> execute(List<M> list)
```

And there are two calls for this method:

```
execute(List<A>);
execute(List<B>);
```

where class `A extends SomeAbstractClass<String>` and `B extends SomeAbstractClass<Void>`.

Is there any way to use ArgumentCaptor for this case?
I want to do something like this:

```
verify(..., times(3)).execute(argumentCaptor.capture())
```

I think (but not sure) this problem can't be solved since A and B doesn't have common ancestor which extends `SomeAbstractClass<R>`.

Anyway, thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution. If anybody interested we can use the following syntax for ArgumentCaptor:

```
ArgumentCaptor<List<? extends SomeAbstractClass>>
```